# SQL Server: update two tables using data from temp table for 200K rows

Tags: sql-server

I have 200K+ rows data in xls and as per requirement i need to update database tables (2 tables) using xls data. 
I know the process to copy data from xls to SQL server table however i am struggling with approach to update database tables.

I could not think of any other approach than writing a cursor and i dont want to go with cursor approach as updating 
200k+ data using cursor may eat up transaction log and will take lot of time to finish the update.

Can someone help me with what else could be done to accomplish this.

Comment: You cannot even search google ? "copy excel file to sql server"

Comment: @user3375857..Google it

Comment: You need to give us more information so we can help. Importing data from excel to SQL Server is doable, updating your table with a JOIN to the imported tables is also doable, so where is your issue?

Comment: I can copy the data from xls to SQL server (it was not a problem for me). But how to update data from temp table to database tables, it is my Q. I have to update data from temp to table a and table b. How to do it without using cursor when same columns from both the tables need to be updated

Comment: Please do not use a cursor?  200 K of separate updates?  The key is to watch out for log file explosion and keep your batches small (5-10K) and use the correct recovery model.  A back up before and after is good for piece of mind!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following techniques.

1 - Import the data into a staging table.  Use the import / export tool is one way to do the task  The target table should be in a throw away or staging database.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

2 - Make sure that the data types between the EXCEL data and TABLE data are the same.

3 - Make sure the existing target [TRG_TBL] TABLE has a primary key.  Make sure the EXCEL data loaded into a [SRC_TBL] table has the same key.  You can add a non-clustered index to speed up the JOIN in the UPDATE statement.

4 - Add a [FLAG] column as INT NULL to the [TRG_TABLE] with an ALTER TABLE command.

5 - Make sure a full backup is done before and after the large UPDATE.  You can also use a DATABASE SNAPSHOT.  The key point is to have a roll back plan in place if needed.

```
-- Select correct db
USE [TRG_DB]
GO

-- Set to simple mode
ALTER DATABASE [TRG_DB] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO

-- Update in batches
DECLARE @VAR_ROWS INT = 1;

WHILE (@VAR_ROWS > 0)
BEGIN
      -- Update fields and flag on join
      UPDATE TOP (10000) T
      SET
        T.FLD1 = S.FLD1,
        -- ... Etc
        T.FLAG = 1
      FROM [TRG_TABLE] T JOIN [SRC_TABLE] S ON T.ID = S.ID
      WHERE T.[FLAG] IS NULL

      -- How many rows updated
      SET @VAR_ROWS = @@ROWCOUNT;

      -- WAL -> flush log entries to data file
      CHECKPOINT;
END

-- Set to full mode
ALTER DATABASE [MATH] SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

In summary, I gave you all the tools to do the job.  Just modify them for your particular occurrence.

PS:  Here is working code from my blog on large deletes.  Same logic applies.

http://craftydba.com/?p=3079

PPS:  I did not check the sample code for syntax.  That is left up for you.

Comment: thanks a ton for your help. It would have been easier if i had to pdate only one table, in my case i need to update two tables using data from temp_table hence i was hoping for cursor based approach. If i am not wrong above approach wont work to update two tables.

Comment: [First], a temp table will use up [TEMPDB].  Be very careful of size.  [Second], I am sure I could figure out how to do use the same loop for a parent/child insertion.  [Instead[ of a flag, 0/1, use a batch counter.  Addition incremental variable. Store that counter in the semaphore [FLAG] in the target table.  Rejoin the target to the source to retrieve any key information from the parent, such as a surrogate key for data warehousing, before inserting into the child.  In short, the cursor routine will be slow.  Any relational solution with indexes will kick it's A$$ on timing.

Comment: to craft dba, thanks a lot for your help. your advise has helped me a lot. i could not see option here to mark your reply as Answer so that you will get due credit for help.